# Screenshot on production server

Tags: c#

I want to take screenshot using websitesscreenshot.com Contact.html. It’s working on my development server but on the production server it’s not working. My production server is secured by SSL. I think this can be region behind it but I’m not sure. Please help me out.

```
WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot _WebsitesScreenshot = new WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot();
WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result _Result ;
string path = null;
path = Server.MapPath(".");
_WebsitesScreenshot.ImageHeight = 300;
_WebsitesScreenshot.ImageWidth = 200;
_Result = _WebsitesScreenshot.CaptureWebpage("www.WebsitesScreenshot.com");
if (_Result == WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result.Captured)
{
    _WebsitesScreenshot.SaveImage(path + "\\WebsitesScreenshot.jpg");
    Response.Write("");
    Response.Write("<img src=WebsitesScreenshot.jpg>");
}
else if (_Result == WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result.Failed)
{
    Response.Write("");
    Response.Write("Failed");
}
else if (_Result == WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result.Timeout)
{
    Response.Write("");
    Response.Write("Timeout");
}
_WebsitesScreenshot.Dispose();
```

Comment: WebsitesScreenshot.com has technical support, why don't you contact them?

Comment: i droped mail befor 40days what no response got